# Wordpress - Error 404 en Paginación con Advanced Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy realizando un trabajo en el que tengo que hacer una paginación de artículos mediante Advanced Custom Field, pero resulta que cuando inicia la Pagina 2 me sale Error 404.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

**page-noticias.php**

PASTEBIN: https://pastebin.com/g4TzTRgL

Y cuando entro por ejemplo a /noticias/page/2/ me sale "Pagina No Encontrada" y deberia mostrarme las otras noticias dentro de la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto muchas posibles soluciones pero ninguna me ha dado resultado hasta el minuto.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando custom post type puedes hacer algo como esto:
Limitar la cantidad de páginas a mostrar antes de ejecutar la consulta

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'paged' => $paged,
'post_type'=> 'tu-post-type',
'order'    => 'DESC'
);              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Especificar la paginación:

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'prev_next'  => true,
    'prev_text'  => __(''),
    'next_text'  => __(''),
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
```